# Stencil Js browser cache issue

Tags: browser-cache, stenciljs

I ran into a caching issue for **snap-ui.esm.js** file. When we create a build in stencil.js we have to include 2 files on a page, **snap-ui.js** and **snap-ui.esm.js**.

The problem is that **snap-ui.esm.js** file contains links to other files that are loaded dynamically and their names are defined when creating the build. And if we created a new build, **snap-ui.esm.js** will contain another links already which is correct but browser may cache **snap-ui.esm.js** with links that don't exist already.

I assume this is not a stencil issue but i faced it during working with stencil.

Please advice how to prevent caching just one js file, in my case it is **snap-ui.esm.js**

Comment: Resource caching by the browser is subject to the `Cache-Control` request and response header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control. But I think your problem may be related to how you deploy. Are those "other files" Stencil files or your own resources?

Comment: "Other files" are Stencil files as well. Stencil build consists of 2 static files a lot of dynamic js files. And if a new build is created, then the name of all other files changes, but the name of the main file, which, in fact, is connected to the page, does not change. But this is the problem, if it is cached, then it will refer to other files of the old build, which are no longer exist.